# How to implement JSON Web token authentication in WCF? What changes are required in config file of WCF?

Tags: wcf

I need to have JSON Web Token Authentication in my WCF service.
I tried different things but nothing is working properly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show us what did you try so far?

Comment: Nothing works is not a good way to represent your problem, Post your code or error message. Or tell us exactly whats happening, we do not have magical powers to see your error screen